# RabbitMQ latency issues across geographical distance

Tags: rabbitmq

We have a situation where we have a single RabbitMQ node in US-East, with producers in other zones (Ireland, Sydney etc). We are seeing huge performance hits when queueing from other zones. Sydney -> US-East queue is 1s to queue a message, whereas queuing Sydney -> Sydney is 50ms. It seems a lot of the time is spent creating the channel and declaring the queue.

What options do we have to improve the performance? Could we look at some sort of distributed RabbitMQ cluster, with a node in each region? Would that help us?

Here's the code we are using to test:

```
var queueConnection = amqp.connect("OUR amqp servers in each region")
var queueName = "test-queue"

var queueMessage = function(message) {
  return queueConnection.then(function(conn) {
    return conn.createChannel()
  }).then(function(ch) {
    var queue = ch.assertQueue(queueName, { durable: false });
    return queue.then(function() {
      ch.sendToQueue(queueName, new Buffer(JSON.stringify(message)), { deliveryMode: true });
      return ch.close()
    });
  })
};

Promise.map(_.range(0, 10), function(item) {
  var timedQueueMessage = timely.promise(queueMessage)
  return timedQueueMessage({ name: "Dom" }).then(function(res) {
    console.log("Completed in " + timedQueueMessage.time + "ms")
  })  
}, { concurrency: 10 }).done(process.exit)
```

Comment: Hard question, Did you try with the shovel plug-in? 
There are lot of ways, for example you could create only one queue as bridge between the brokers and buffer-aggregate and compress the messages to reduce the bytes you have to send.

Comment: I am familiar with the byte level details of creating a channel. While I am not as familiar with what RMQ does in the process of creating a queue behind the scenes, I do not believe any input is required from the client. Therefore I must conclude that something else is going on with your inter-regional connections. There is not nearly enough data exchanged in this process to create a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

For these use cases you should look at Federation or Shovel.

This page explains the pros and cons of each of the distributed options offered by RabbitMQ: http://www.rabbitmq.com/distributed.html